# The banner on my website is not showing up (HTML)

Tags: html, css, header, banner

I put a banner in the div tags except it is not showing on my website. Here is my html:

```css
    .alert-box {
        background-color: #DB5461;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 23px;
        padding: 13px 16px;
        text-align:center;
        font-family: "Plus Jakarta Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
        #header {
          background-image: url(“./background.jpg”);
          background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          position: relative;
          background-size: cover;
          top: 0;
          height: 40px;
          width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="header">
      <div class="alert-box">
        <span class="badge">Announcement</span>Announcement text here (I'm not sharing this)
      </div><br>
    </div>
```

I don't see an evident problem.

I have tried changing up the CSS to no avail, and I believe the HTML is fine.

Comment: It displays in the code shown here.  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  Or, worst case, link to one?

Comment: it works here, and I do not know what's wrong on your website, maybe other element hide them, you can add *z-index: 100; position: absolute;* to test the code.

Comment: [My Github](https://github.com/Cerealistic/Cerealistic.github.io) Here is my github so you can see my full code. @David

Comment: @TheCerealist: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @TheCerealist: If you have a live *running* example which demonstrates the problem, that could potentially be useful.  But just linking to your GitHub repository is basically saying, "Here's all of my code, most of which is unrelated.  Go debug it for me."

Comment: @David sorry for that. I was attempting to show that I am running github pages. [Github Pages](https://Cerealistic.github.io)

Comment: @TheCerealist: Ok, but what isn't working as expected on that demo?  The question above sounds like an announcement banner element isn't being displayed, but on that page it is being displayed.

Comment: @David its not the announcement banner it's the image that I am trying to put behind it. The id="header" part should have set a background banner for the top of the page.

Comment: @TheCerealist: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  If you open those tools, you can observe the 404 error being returned by the server when requesting the image.  The URL of that request reveals the problem, which appears to just be a typo.  For some reason you're using stylized double-quote characters instead of regular ASCII double-quote characters.  This is essentially a syntax error, and one of countless reasons why a word processor is not an IDE.

Comment: @David Just changed now. Thank you for this and I hope it fixed it. I never thought to check the devtools for errors!